# UK visa individual merits

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

What does this mean:

> Any future UK visa applications you make will be considered on their individual merits.

Comment: I'm flagging to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be an English language question, not a travel-related question.

Comment: Isn't that statment followed by a clause similar to this: *however you are likely to be refused unless the circumstances of your application change.* If so, it is advising that that there would have to be fundamental changes (such as finances, employment, home ties, premise) would be necessary in order for a future application to succeed.

Answer (score 6):

It means that if you make another application, that application will be given its own assessment to decide if it will be granted. Just because a previous application failed it doesn't mean the new one will fail.

HOWEVER...

Your previous applications are going to be part of assessing the new one. If your new application contains information that contradicts a previous one, or if you made false statements on a previous one, or the changes in circumstance are implausible, then that will have an effect on the new assessment. They can use information you provided in a previous application in making the new assessment.

Also assessments are fairly standardized. So if you make an application that fails, and then submit a virtually identical application in which your circumstances are the same, it is very likely that one will fail too.

Answer (score 0):

‘Merit’ means ‘worth’ - that is, each application is assessed based on what is stated in and provided with that application.

Comment: So does that mean they will not go back to previous applications and thank you?

Comment: @DabbashWail Probably not. The most I think you can expect it to mean is that future applications won't be rejected because you've had a previous application rejected (or that future applications won't be approved because you've had a previous application approved). However, the "individual merits" of a new application may include how the statements made match what you've said in past applications.

Comment: @Dabbash Wail No, they will assess the application as submitted. They will however take into account your immigration history, including any previous refusals as the full text contained in a standard refusal notice indicates per @Giorgio’s comment. You should perhaps read this question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e before reapplying